# Remove duplicated strings from character vector

Tags: r

How can I efficiently remove duplicates from this character vector ?

```
> dput(data[1:30])
c("AT2G27020 AT3G26340", "AT1G56450 AT3G26340", "AT1G13060 AT3G26340", 
"AT3G22630 AT3G26340", "AT3G22110 AT3G26340", "AT2G05840 AT3G26340", 
"AT1G47250 AT3G26340", "AT1G79210 AT3G26340", "AT2G27020 AT5G40580", 
"AT3G27430 AT5G40580", "AT4G31300 AT5G40580", "AT3G14290 AT5G40580", 
"AT3G22630 AT5G40580", "AT3G22110 AT5G40580", "AT5G35590 AT5G40580", 
"AT2G05840 AT5G40580", "AT3G60820 AT5G40580", "AT1G79210 AT5G40580", 
"AT2G27020 AT3G27430", "AT2G27020 AT4G31300", "AT1G53850 AT2G27020", 
"AT2G27020 AT5G66140", "AT2G27020 AT3G51260", "AT1G21720 AT2G27020", 
"AT1G56450 AT2G27020", "AT1G13060 AT2G27020", "AT2G27020 AT3G22630", 
"AT2G27020 AT4G14800", "AT2G27020 AT3G22110", "AT2G27020 AT5G35590"
)
```

I have tried to use simple functions as: `unique` and `duplicated` but unfortunately it didn't work.

That's my bad. By duplicates I mean the same AGIs so it doesn't matter that some of them are stored together in "". I would like to have each "ATXG..." just one time in my vector. I didn't know at the begining that vector contains pairs of them... Sorry.

Comment: What exactly did you try to do (code) and what didn't work? `unique` and `duplicated` work on the _entire_ string. What "duplicates" are you trying to remove?

Comment: your example doesn't contain duplicates...

Comment: Your strings are in the format `"text1 text2"`. Are you looking to see if the two values are equal to each other? `text1 == text2`?

Comment: Look at edit, please. Sorry for the problem. The format of the strings is not correct. Every `textx` should be treated separately, not two strings stored together in "".

Comment: Not completely sure what you're after yet but `unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))` might do it.

Comment: It works ok. Sorry for not explaining exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
 #[1] "AT2G27020" "AT3G26340" "AT1G56450" "AT1G13060" "AT3G22630" "AT3G22110"
 #[7] "AT2G05840" "AT1G47250" "AT1G79210" "AT5G40580" "AT3G27430" "AT4G31300"
#[13] "AT3G14290" "AT5G35590" "AT3G60820" "AT1G53850" "AT5G66140" "AT3G51260"
#[19] "AT1G21720" "AT4G14800"
```